# In Python, how do I read an input file to then translate it to morse code?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, input

I have to create a program that asks the user for an input file, and then creates an output file containing the message encoded in Morse code. When I run my program, there's a type error in the "translated += alphabet[words]" line, it says it's an unhashable type: 'list'. How can I translate the text in the input file to morse code after opening it?

Is the problem with my code after the function?

```
inputFileName = input("Enter the input file name:")

outputFileName = input("Enter the output file name:")

def morseCode(inputFileName):
    inputFileName = inputFileName.upper()
    translated = ""
    # Open the input and output files 
    with open(inputFileName) as inputFile, open (outputFileName, "w") as outputFile:
        for line in inputFile:
            words = line.split()
            # Translate letters in dictionary 
            translated += alphabet[line]
            for word in words:
                if word in inputFileName:
                    outputFile.write(inputFile[word])
                else:
                    outputFile.write(word)
                outputFile.write(' ')
            outputFile.write('\n')

            return (outputFile, inputFile, inputFileName, translated)

translated = morseCode(inputFileName)


print(translated)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a dict of characters to morse, you can use a simple list comprehension and the `dict.get()` feature to translate to Morse. Note, this converts any non alpha-numeric characters to a space. As you can see in the other answer, you can easily add those characters to your dict. One key you need to pay attention to is the `str.upper()` method. This will make sure that all the characters have a match since Morse is case insensitive.

```
def txt_2_morse(msg):

    morse = {
        'A':'.-', 'B':'-...', 'C':'-.-.', 'D':'-..', 'E':'.',
        'F':'..-.', 'G':'--.', 'H':'....', 'I':'..', 'J':'.---',
        'K':'-.-', 'L':'.-..', 'M':'--', 'N':'-.', 'O':'---',
        'P':'.--.', 'Q':'--.-', 'R':'.-.', 'S':'...', 'T':'-',
        'U':'..-', 'V':'...-', 'W':'.--', 'X':'-..-', 'Y':'-.--',
        'Z':'--..', '1':'.----', '2':'..---', '3':'...--', '4':'....-',
        '5':'.....', '6':'-....', '7':'--...', '8':'---..', '9':'----.',
        '0':'-----'}

    return "".join([morse.get(c.upper(), ' ') for c in msg])

print(txt_2_morse("Hello World"))
# ......-...-..--- .-----.-..-..-..
```

So, if you want to read a file in line by line into an output file, you can simply parse each line individually.

```
with open('inputfile.txt') as infile:
    with open('outputfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write("{}\n".format(txt_2_morse(line)))
```

Input:

```
this is a file
with a few lines in it
to demonstrate code
```

Output:

```
-......... ..... .- ..-....-... 
.--..-.... .- ..-...-- .-....-..... ..-. ..- 
---- -...------....-.-..--. -.-.---.
```

Comment: Thank you! That actually helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad to help. If this solved your issue, go ahead and accept the answer. Otherwise, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: For next time, I guess I'm still curious of what was wrong with "translated += alphabet[line]". I was getting this error: "KeyError: 'ABCDE FGHIJ KLMNO PQRST UVWXYZ' " which was just repeating the contents of my data file back to me.

Comment: I don't see where you define `alphabet` so it's tough to tell, but if it's similar to my `morse` dict, then it looks like you're trying to get the value where you are using an entire line of text as the key to the dict. I think you were looking to pass characters, not whole lines of text. That's where `''.join([convert(char) for char in str])` comes in.

Answer (score 1):

```
MORSE_CODE_DICT = { 'A':'.-', 'B':'-...', 
                    'C':'-.-.', 'D':'-..', 'E':'.', 
                    'F':'..-.', 'G':'--.', 'H':'....', 
                    'I':'..', 'J':'.---', 'K':'-.-', 
                    'L':'.-..', 'M':'--', 'N':'-.', 
                    'O':'---', 'P':'.--.', 'Q':'--.-', 
                    'R':'.-.', 'S':'...', 'T':'-', 
                    'U':'..-', 'V':'...-', 'W':'.--', 
                    'X':'-..-', 'Y':'-.--', 'Z':'--..', 
                    '1':'.----', '2':'..---', '3':'...--', 
                    '4':'....-', '5':'.....', '6':'-....', 
                    '7':'--...', '8':'---..', '9':'----.', 
                    '0':'-----', ', ':'--..--', '.':'.-.-.-', 
                    '?':'..--..', '/':'-..-.', '-':'-....-', 
                    '(':'-.--.', ')':'-.--.-'} 

 def encrypt(message):
    cipher = ''
    message_upper=message.upper()
    for letter in message_upper:
        if letter != ' ':
            if letter in MORSE_CODE_DICT:
                cipher += MORSE_CODE_DICT[letter] + ' '
            else:
                cipher+=letter
        else:
             cipher += ' '
    return cipher

O/P:-
>>> encrypt('I like apples + bananas!')
'..  .-.. .. -.- .  .- .--. .--. .-.. . ...  + -... .- -. .- -. .- ... !'
```

Comment: What happens when you pass in lower case characters or characters that aren't in the dict? like `I like apples + bananas!`